# Delete all files in folder and all subfolders (compresed folders)

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I would like to delete al files in this directory containing the string *copy of*.
But the command

```
  del /s *copy of*
```

does not seem to do the trick.
The folders and files are compressed could that be the problem?

[image: Compressed files]

[EDIT]

I found the error. the command stops when it encounters a file he cannot delete because of the path that is to long. Any command that I can execute that skips those files? Or better deletes them anyway?

Comment: Type `del /S "*Copy of*"`...

Comment: Nope the problems seems to be that the command does not enter the subfolders, when I execute it in one of the folders it works but not outside of the folder..

Comment: @Anthonygesquière Open a command prompt window and run `del /?` to get output the help for this command. Run `del /F /Q /S "*Copy of*"` which works also on NTFS compressed folders. But this command does not remove files matching the wildcard pattern inside of ZIP files from the ZIP archives. Some people mistakenly think ZIP files are compressed folders, but that is not true, although Windows Explorer supports opening ZIP files like a folder and extracting files from the compressed archive. The command __DEL__ of Windows command interpreter does not support ZIP decompression.

Comment: I found the error. the command stops when it encounters a file he cannot delete because of the path that is to long. Any command that I can execute that skips those files? Or better deletes them anyway?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Remove-Item -Path "C:\Temp\*" -Filter "*copy of*"
```